# Can't launch Ubuntu (or any Linux) on hi-end hardware?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, 11.10, hardware, debian

there a though one: I've bough a new computer with the following configuration:

> ASUS Rampage III Extreme
>   Core i7 950
>   ZOTAC AMP! GeForce GTX 560
>   KINGSTON KHX1600C9D3K3 3x4GB
>   HAF 922
>   OCZ FATAL1TY 750W
>   SEAGATE 500GB ST3500413AS

After installation of **any** Linux I can't lauch it! After grub screen, when it's supposed to launch system it gets stuck with black-screen(debian) or purple-sceen(ubuntu).

I installed various versions of **Ubuntu**, **Debian** with and without X, **Fedora**. Every time it's the same: total freeze after grub.

Can anyone help me, please? I **don't want** to stuck with **windows** (which is running perfectly as never)!

Comment: Hi! Do you install `/boot` dir to unencrypted, unLVM-ed place? It must be accessable at boot time!

Comment: /boot is on same partition as /.<br>
no encrption, no LVMs

Comment: :( 9.10 version? try it!

Comment: Do you get a login prompt if you press alt+ctrl+f1 when you have that purple screen? If so, then you might have to install a driver for your VGA.

Comment: @seler - when booting - press shift to display your grub and add boot options `nomodeset xforcevesa acpi=off` - that should get you a low res desktop.  Experiment booting with combinations of those boot options - see my answer here for some more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro: It's abandoned as the idea is. I'm now running Debian as VM under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest checking your BIOS for bootloading settings. By default configurations are set for DOS, change to it Other/Linux/etc.
I hope it works.